# Why does of copy() method of CGImage results in an image on same memory address?

Tags: ios, swift, pointers

I am currently struggling with the `copy` method of `CGImage` (or with how `CGImage` works in general?).

Background: I manipulated an image with an `UnsafeMutablePointer` and got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I figured out, that this was caused by the `CGImage` already displayed in an `UIView` (encapsulated in an `UIImage`). So I created a copy of the `CGImage` and it works. From this I conclude, that `copy`must create a real copy of the image.

BUT: While checking the pointers with the code below I noticed that the address the two pointer pointing to are the same.

How can this be?

```
import UIKit

var uiImageIn = UIImage(named: "image2.png")!

var image1 = uiImageIn.cgImage!
var image2 = image1.copy()!

var ptr1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.init(mutating: CFDataGetBytePtr(image1.dataProvider!.data)!)
var ptr2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.init(mutating: CFDataGetBytePtr(image2.dataProvider!.data)!)

print("Image1Ptr: \(ptr1)")
print("Image2Ptr: \(ptr2) --> Same result as for ptr1!?")
```

I would expect ptr1 and ptr2 to be different here.

**Update**

OK, figured out my error:
It is not necessary to create a copy of `CGImage` at all, as accessing the `dataProvider` creates a **copy** of the bitmap data already. BUT: In my code above I did not assign the `dataProvider` to any variable. Therefore it gets freed instantly and the address is reused most of the time (additionally it leads to an error if I access data via one of the pointers as `dataProvider` is freed already).

In the following example the addresses of the pointers are different:
    import UIKit

```
var uiImageIn = UIImage(named: "image.png")!

var image1 = uiImageIn.cgImage!

var data1 = image1.dataProvider!.data
var data2 = image1.dataProvider!.data

var ptr1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.init(mutating: CFDataGetBytePtr(data1)!)
var ptr2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.init(mutating: CFDataGetBytePtr(data2)!)

print("Image1Ptr: \(ptr1)")
print("Image2Ptr: \(ptr2)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong. `copy()` creates a shallow copy. That means a new object is created, but all the internal structures are copied only by reference. That means that even if you receive a new `CGImage`, the data providers will be still the same object (and pointer).

Also note that with immutable objects the `copy` function does not have to necessarily return a new object. It can just return the previous object (which is what would happen with `NSArray` for example).

Modifying `data` inside the provider of random `CGImage` is not probably a good thing to do anyway because you don't know the internal structure of the data (is it JPEG data source? is it PNG data source? is it a bitmap?)

Comment: OK, that makes sense. But I don‘t get why I get an error if I manipulate image data of an image displayed in an UIView but do not get this error if I manipulate the copy?

Comment: @JPS It's not clear how you are trying to modify the data. However, a `UIImageView` probably somehow detects the changes inside its `CGImage` reference and that could be broken when you create a copy. It's possible that you will get the same crash later during a repaint.

Comment: Updated the question with some new insights. Regarding the manipulation of the image data: This is without risk, as CGImage data is bitmap despite the original format. As you pointed me in the right direction I accept it as answer :-)